# Using Makefile to run multiple programs

Tags: makefile

Whenever I try to run this, the only output I get is "make: foo.o is up to date." It seems as if the rest of the program does not run and I do not know why. My instructions are as follows: "Compile a C program. Run a C program. Run a Python program. Compile and run a java program. Check for a README, display it. Compare 2 files. Clean up intermediary files."

```
cc = gcc
EXE = foo
JAVAC = javac
JRE = java
PAGER = less
TEST_OUT = test.out
EXP_OUT = expected.out

foo.o: foo.c foo.h
        $(cc) -c foo.c

main.o: main.c foo.h
        $(cc) -c main.c

$(EXE): foo.o main.o
        $(cc) -o$(EXE) main.o foo.o

run-c: $(EXE)
        ./$(EXE)

run-py:
        ./foo.py

read: README
        $(PAGER)

foo.class: foo.java
        $(JAVAC) foo.java

run-java: foo.cass
        $(JRE) foo

save-java:
        ./(run-java) >> $(TEST_OUT)

test-java: $(TEST_OUT) $(EXP_OUT)
        @if diff $(TEST_OUT) $(EXP_OUT) &> /dev/null ; then \
                echo "Passed!" ;\
        else \
                echo "Not the same!" ;\
        fi

clean:
        -rm test.out
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I try to run this, the only output I get is "make: foo.o is up to date."

By default, `make` runs the topmost rule when no target is specified. You have to run for example `make run-c` to invoke a corresponding recipe, or you can just put an `all` rule before any others which depends on *and* does all the things.

> ```
> read: README
>         $(PAGER)
> ```

I suspect you might have missed putting `$@` after `$(PAGER)` as the argument.

> ```
> save-java:
>     ./(run-java) >> $(TEST_OUT)
> ```

You can't just "include" other recipes this way. Instead, repeat what's in `run-java` and append the redirection.

If you want to specify "pseudo" targets, I recommend you to specify them as `.PHONY`, such as:

```
.PHONY: all run-c run-py run-java save-java test-java clean
```

To mark some targets as intermediate files, use the `.INTERMEDIATE` directive. GNU Make manual (texinfo) is available both [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/) and via the `info` command.